# add a webextension page de startup pages list after user confirmation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Using a chrome web extension (or a normal web page), i'm trying to add an extension page to startup pages list.

I know about the directive in the manifest:

```
"chrome_settings_overrides"  : {
    "startup_pages" : ["https://example.com/..."]
 }
```

the problem with that is that it adds the page statically without user explicit permission. I'm looking for a script that could do that instead.

thank you for your help n_n

Comment: i could'nt open tab when extension starts using tabs API because inspectors will signal the app as a malware. and because i need that the param to be in chrome settings and not in mines.

Comment: There's [no such API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)

Comment: Why can't you use the tabs api? Who are "inspectors" and why would they think opening a tab constitutes malware?